# What is the equivalent of listview.getCount in case of Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have used `listview.getCount()` how can I get count in case of `Recyclerview`

```
id = receiver + "-" + splashList.getCount();
```

Customized method in adapter:

```
public void setImage(String my_image, String r_image) {
    byte[] decodedrimage = Base64.decode(r_image, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedrByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedrimage, 0,
            decodedrimage.length);
    if (my_image.equals("empty")) {
        imgflag = 1;
    } else {
        byte[] decodedmyimage = Base64.decode(my_image, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedmyByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                decodedmyimage, 0, decodedmyimage.length);
        rimage = createCirclebitmap(decodedrByte);
        myimage = createCirclebitmap(decodedmyByte);
    }

}
```

and calling of the method in another class:

```
CustomListAdapter1 mAdapter ;
mAdapter = new CustomListAdapter1(NewUI.this, dummy,
                imgpath, bitmap, id, dateList);
mAdapter.setImage(myimage, rimage);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

there is no equivalent. The `RecyclerView` has no direct knowledge of the underlying dataset. The closest thing is

```
int count = 0;
if (recyclerViewInstance.getAdapter() != null) {
     count = recyclerViewInstance.getAdapter().getItemCount();
}
```

or if you have a reference to your adapter, simply call

```
  int count = 0;
  if (mAdapter != null) {
     count = mAdapter.getItemCount();
  }
```

Comment: ok..can you please tell me if i define a method in recycler view adapter class..how can i call that method from another class where i set the adapter

Comment: what kind of method? If it is a custom method, nothing you override from the super class, then you need either a reference to the specific instance or you have to cast the return value of `getAdapter()` to the specific subclass, and access the method with the `.` operator

Comment: it is a custom method..and i am calling using adapter.getimage(string,string)..but it is showing an error

Comment: then keep a reference to the Adapter.`MyAdapter adp = new ...; mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adp)`. and then use `adp.getImage(...)`

Comment: i have done the same..but still getting an error as cannot resolve the method

Comment: cannot resolve method 'setImage(java.lang.string,java.lang.string)'

Comment: thankyou soo much..and sorry for wasting ur time..i've done such a silly mistake..the issue is resolved...thanku

Answer (score 1):

```
//use this method to return recycler adapter item count..
private int recyclerCount(){
 int Count = 0;
  if (mAdapter != null) {
     count = mAdapter.getItemCount();
  }
return count;
}
```

Comment: make sure you use "count" instead of "Count" as you'll get an error of 'variable not found'

Comment: Use `int count = 0;` instead of `Count`